# How do undo a changeset in VSOnline?

Tags: tfs

I have several changes that were checked in by another developer and I would like to undo these changes and check in the changes in multiple changesets for easier migration through branches.

can this be done?

thx

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using VS2013 and TFS2013.

If you're using TFVC (i.e. not git) then find the changeset you want to undo, right click it and select "Rollback Entire Changeset". It will create a set of pending changes that reverse the changeset. Check those changes in. After that you can then manually redo the changes you want in smaller chunks and commit them as you see fit.

If you're using git, then you can simply use git commands to reset your branch to a commit before the one you want to ignore. From there, again, make the changes you want.

In either case I'd copy your code to a different folder on your local drive first so that you have something to refer to when redoing the changes since the steps above will change your working folder's contents.